# PHP Session Getting CorrectValue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session, post

Question: What to do to fix my problem on handling the session because it is returning an incorrect value.
Situation: I'm having problem on this session variable from the table. I added data from database to a table using while loop. Here is my code:

```
                    <form action="edit2.php" method="get">
                            <?php

                    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
                    mysql_select_db("ispot", $link);

                    $result4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_ispot", $link);
                    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result4);


                $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM complaints");

                    echo "<table border='1'>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Id Number</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Problem</th>
                    <th>Date Reported</th>
                    <th>Complaint ID </th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>";

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {

                echo "<tr>";


                echo "<td name=id_num>" . $row['id_number'] . "</td>";
                $_SESSION['favcolor'] = "$row[id_number]";
                echo "<td name=remarks>" . $row['remarks'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td name=status>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td name=date>" . $row['date_reported'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<INPUT TYPE = text Name = cid VALUE = " . $row['complaint_id'] . ">" . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . "<INPUT TYPE = Submit Name = Submit1 VALUE =Edit>" . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";

            }
                    echo "</table>" ;?>
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

As you can see, there is the edit button, where I can edit a specific row  in the table. 
When I press the edit button, this will show:

[image]

Notice that the User ID is wrong, what can I do to fix it? because the user id that is being post here was the last user_id that was inserted in the table.

And here is my code for the second image:

```
<b>Date:</b> <input type='text' name='today' placeholder='<?php echo $today ?>' disabled='disabled'> <br><br>
    <b>User ID:</b> <input type='text' disabled='disables' name='userid' placeholder='<?php

                //$comid = $_GET["cid"];
                //echo $userid;
                echo $_SESSION['userid'];

                //$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE id = XXX");
                //$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                //print_r($row);


                    //$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE complaint_id = '$comid'", $link);
                    //$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM complaints", $link);
                    //while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
                    //{
                    //echo $row['id_number'];

                    //}


            ?>'></br><br>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use the session, it's entirely inappropriate for what you want to do. Send the corresponding ID for the row that they clicked the edit button for to the server.

Comment: You're setting the SESSION variable on every iteration of the loop. So when the loop terminates, the value is set to that of the final iteration.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist sir, I also tried not to use session,but still the same problem . .

Comment: Try using <a> tag and pass $row[id_number] as a parameter, it will make it alot easier..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i replaced the button with a link, used it to pass the value when edit is clicked, catch the value with a get and it works for me.

in edit.php

```
echo "<td> <a href = 'edit2.php?id=$num_id'>Edit</a></td>";
```

in edit2.php

```
    $id = $_GET['id'];

<b>User ID:</b> <input type='text' disabled='disables' name='userid' value = '<?php echo $id;?>'></input type>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE complaint_id = '$comid'", $link);
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM complaints", $link);
```

You must use just one of them this rows. I think problem is the second row. This query not choose the "id" that is "comid".

Your first query row is enough:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE complaint_id = '$comid'", $link);
```

Comment: Hi sir, so... I changed my code to my previous code, but still gives the same result.. `$comid = $_GET["cid"]; $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM complaints WHERE complaint_id = '$comid'", $link);
      //$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM complaints", $link);
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
      {
      echo $row['id_number'];
      
      }`

Comment: Hmm... Please try `mysql_fetch_array` instead of `mysql_fetch_assoc`